# Support Website for My iOS App, any suggestions?

Tags: ios, url, app-store

I'm getting ready to set up a website for my support URL for the app before I submit to the App Store. I was thinking I'll probably just do a WordPress site. Any thoughts or suggestions? I'd love to get some links to some good themes, on the cheap.

Answer (score 6):

You could set up a simple static page on github, if you're using that to host your source (or even if not): http://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of WordPress themes out there for app websites. Here's one I ran across a while back: http://www.appdesignvault.com/darstell-iphone-wordpress-theme/.

It's free if you tweet about them! Am considering using this for my app, or using it as a starting point for my own wordpress theme.

This is a brief review of some paid themes. Most are inexpensive. (note: website seems to load slow)

- http://www.devlounge.net/design/6-wordpress-themes-for-iphone-apps/

Here's some others. I haven't looked into them much though.

- http://www.apptamin.com/app-websites/
- http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/myapp/
- http://templatic.com/cms-themes/iphone-app/

Good luck!

Comment: Chris, noticed you haven't accepted an answer. If any of these (don't care if it's mine or not) answer your question, please accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm hosting a static site on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) for [Railscasts for iOS](http://www.railscastsforios.info/). It's free and barely requires any maintenance.